# Serverless Framework / Python for Lambda - packaging up local shared libraries

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Python package novice here. I'm working in Python and using the serverless framework for stack config and deployment. I have a file structure like this:

```
libs/
  __init__.py
  mylib.py
services/
  service1/
    handler.py
```

handler.py needs to reference mylib.py, so it includes it:

```
from libs.mylib include MyLib
```

My virtual env is set up to add the project root to PYTHONPATH, so this works on my local dev, but `libs/mylib.py` doesn't get included when I package it up for Lambda. How do I tell serverless to include the libs file in the package?

I've tried including a relative path in my requirements.txt file from both the `services/service1/` path and from the root path - both have resulted in an error like this:

```
  STDERR: ERROR: Invalid requirement: './libs' (from line 1 of /var/task/requirements.txt)
  Hint: It looks like a path. File './libs' does not exist.
```

I've also tried including `libs` without a path, and that just installs the pypi package.

Comment: Can you post your serverless.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a couple of days. The serverless-python-requirements was excluding the `lib` directory because it was outside of the `module` configuration I set.

The solution for me was to move the requirements.txt into the root directory and set up the `module` configuration also to the root.

Could you post your serverless file?

Comment: Any other solution other than moving requirements.txt file